# Folders & Files are being moved to the root ... why, what is causing it and how to fix it?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, onedrive-for-business

We have a problem where Folders & Files are getting moved to the [root] location within a SharePoint document library.  Even if you manually move the files to original folders, it will be moved back.
Some [online sources](https://www.jecal22.com/sharepoint-online-office-365-files-mysteriously-move-from-subdirectories-to-documents-root/) say that the OneDrive for Business is causing the problem.
However, it is not clear `what is causing` this behaviour and how to `avoid` it. 
Anybody here has been through this and found a reason of the problem?

Resetting the OneDrive may solve the problem but it won't move back the folders/files to original state. 
How would you approach this problem? Manual work or ... is there a trick?

We use: SharePoint 2016 on-prem

Comment: Do you have any custom event receivers or features installed on your environment?

Comment: @CallumCrowley no, but users use OneDrive for Business to synchronise data from document libraries.